# declare a variable withour var inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

In JavaScript the execution of code takes in 2 phases. In first step it is read and the space is reserved for variables(given value `undefined` initially) and functions. In the second phase it is executed line by line.

And also I read that the variables declared without `var` keyword are set as `Global` variables.

So if I print a variable before defining it inside a function, it should print `undefined`. Like in the code below:

```js
b();

console.log(a);
console.log(d);
var a = 'Hello World!';

function b() {
  console.log(c);
  console.log('Called b!');
  var c = "variable c is printed";
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
  d = "Variable d is printed";
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
undefined
Called b!
variable c is printed
undefined
Variable d is printed
```

But I get the below output:

```
undefined
Called b!
variable c is printed
Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined
    at b (app.js:12)
    at app.js:1
```

So my doubt is, when function `b` is called, then in the first phase of code execution, variable `d` should be given space and value `undefined` initially. And then the execution should begin line by line in the second phase.

Comment: A variable is only "given space" when it is declared with `var`/`let`/`const`. If it isn't, then it won't be "given space" and the behaviour when trying to access it depends entirely on runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And also I read that the variables declared without var keyword are set as Global variables.

Yes, kind of. What happens is that if you do an assignment, like

```
 d = 1;
```

The engine goes up through all *environment records* (the place were values of variables are stored at runtime), so in your case it first goes to `b`s record, and then to the global record. If it finds a variable binding (name -> value) in one of those records (which were created when execution starts, just as you said), it then stores the value there. However if it reaches the global record, and does not find a binding along the way (the variable is *undeclared*), it just creates a new binding at that global record.

So by the time you do `console.log(d)`, no binding for `d` exists, and accessing `d` fails.

Comment: So, in the first phase, when it does not see var behind d, what will happen. What I understood according to your answer is it will leave it. Then in the second phase only, when it won't find it in any record, then it will define it in global record, i.e., at the time of execution.

Comment: In the first phase, it will only do something with `var`, `let`, `const`, `class` and `function`

Answer (score 0):

In first Phase When try to set space for Variables Find them by Keywords:

```
var/let/const
```

When you don't use it in second Phase crashed variables pointer where not exist space for them, In function scope d don't have any space and its a crash point.

this code show what happened:

```js
console.log(a);
a = 'Some Value For A Variable';
```

to solve it two solution:

1- use Keywords

```js
console.log(a);
var a = 'Some Value For A Variable';
```

2- Initializing First

```js
a = 'Some Value For A Variable';
console.log(a);
```

The Best Clear Code is Complex of two Solution:
* use keywords
* call variables after definition

```js
var a = 'Some Value For A Variable';
console.log(a);
```

Good Luck